# VB.Net 2005, how can I subtract a date from the (current date minus 7 days) and produce a number of days?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I have a date in the future e.g. 13/10/2008 I need to subtract the current date (today is the 28/09/2010) minus 7 days, so thats 21/09/2010 minus 13/10/2008, which would equal erm, 720 something ?

But the current date won't always be 28/09/2010, obviously.

I need the code for this.

EDIT: When i said future I mean past :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dt As DateTime = New DateTime(2008, 10, 13)
    ' be careful what you are subtracting from what
    ' the date you have is not in the future (year 2008)
    ' if the date is in the future: (dt.Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))).TotalDays
    ' or simply take the absolute value
    Dim days As Double = (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Subtract(dt)).TotalDays
    Console.WriteLine(days)
End Sub
```

You will also notice that the [TotalDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) property is of type [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx).

Comment: Error 1 Operator '-' is not defined for types 'Date' and 'Object'.

Comment: Right, sorry, I didn't see you was using VS2005 which doesn't support variable type inference. Please see my update. Types need to be specified when declaring the variables.

Comment: Still getting the same error with your edited code 
    
Error 1 Operator '-' is not defined for types 'Date' and 'Object'.

Comment: That's very strange. How about: `(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Subtract(dt)).TotalDays`?

Answer (score 1):

13/10/2008 is not exactly in the future :)

Sorry for using C# code, but:

```
(dateInFuture - DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)).TotalDays
```

Should work. Of course the other way around if you mean in the past:

```
(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) - dateInPast).TotalDays
```

Comment: Hmmm, having trouble converting that to vb http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 1):

```
        Dim ValidDate As Date =cDate("Tuesday, December 31, 2013") 'A date in Future

        Dim date1 As New System.DateTime(ValidDate.Year, ValidDate.Month, ValidDate.Day)
        Dim date2 = Now

        Dim Diff1 As System.TimeSpan

        Diff1 = date1.Subtract(date2)

        Dim TotRemDays = (Int(Diff1.TotalDays))

        MsgBox(TotRemDays)
```

Answer (score 0):

"I need the code for this" seems a bit too much like "Plz give meh teh codez", and your "date in the future" seems a little bit in the past.

Anyway, you should investigate the relevant methods of the `DateTime` structure, in particular the [Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method (both overloads, or in alternative its subtraction operator), and you should have a look at the [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) structure too.

You could create a `DateTime` for the date of today, subtract a `TimeSpan` of 7 days to it, and then subtract such result to a `DateTime` representing your date in the future (or, if it is in the past, do the opposite). You'll get a `TimeSpan` representing the difference in time between the two dates, from which you can easily get the number of days using its `Days` property.

As other said, to do the first subtraction you can also use the `AddDays` method of the `DateTime` structure.

Comment: There would be no need for sites this like at all if all answers to questions were google it and find out, lol

Comment: Learning to program is learning to put the bricks together. Providing a ready-made answer makes sense for complicated problems, but when all the problem is "find me a call in the library that does what I want" the best answer for me is to gently point to the documentation. Notice that I didn't say "just google it", I provided you some pointers to the relevant sections of the MSDN, so in future you'll be able to sort out such kind of small problems by yourself. And keep in mind that I would have spent less time just providing you teh codez, but that would be spoon-feeding you - useless at most.